# How to update sendlog data extension after the email launch that has no primary key

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, jquery, email-studio

We launched the ABC campaign newsletter to a 30000 target audience. Unfortunately, the subscriber key's email address was mapped incorrectly and the email launched. After the email launch, all email target audience details are stored incorrectly in the sendlog data extension. We noticed an error while querying the sendlog data. Now how to update the correct email address to the subscriber key. There is no primary in the sendlog data extension to update the data.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no primary key then you cannot update specific rows. Update works only for DEs with PK.

What you could do instead is to copy all records from sendlog to another DE where you will set the PKs. Perform the edits and then select all and overwrite the sendlog with all data (including fixed rows).

Alternatively you can perform similar using import activity.

Hope that helps.